# Cmake/MSBuild failed while preparing project for Visual Studio because user home path contains parenthesis

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

### Summary

Cmake/MSBuild failed while preparing project for Visual Studio because user home path contains parenthesis

- user account (domain, created using email) obtained name like **PřijmeníJménoXXXXXX(** (original string "PřijmeníJménoXXXXXX(12345)" was cropped to 20 characters)
- source and build folders are placed outside of C:\Users\PřijmeníJménoXXXXXX(
- the problem is parenthesis at the end of username. This parenthesis is missing in the command in the cmake/msbuild log

```
:VCEnd
      'C:\Users\PřijmeníJménoXXXXXX' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
```

- parentheses in *Program Files (x86)* don't seem to be a problem (probably)
- Why/What is it trying to call from user folder?

Software versions: Visual Studio 19, Cmake 14 and 15, Windows 10 Pro

Cmake log:

```
PS G:\build> cmake ..\source_dir\
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- project source directory -> G:/source_dir
-- project build directory -> G:/build
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (project):
  Failed to run MSBuild command:

    C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe

  to get the value of VCTargetsPath:

    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.1.76+g14b0a930a7 for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    Build started 10/4/2019 9:14:12 PM.
    Project "G:\build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
    PrepareForBuild:
      Creating directory "x64\Debug\".
      Creating directory "x64\Debug\VCTargetsPath.tlog\".
    InitializeBuildStatus:
      Creating "x64\Debug\VCTargetsPath.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
    PostBuildEvent:
      echo VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\

      :VCEnd
      'C:\Users\PřijmeníJménoXXXXXX' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: The command "echo VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\ [G:\build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [G:\build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    Done Building Project "G:\build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

    Build FAILED.

    "G:\build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
    (PostBuildEvent target) ->
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: The command "echo VCTargetsPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\ [G:\build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(138,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [G:\build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj]

        0 Warning(s)
        1 Error(s)

    Time Elapsed 00:00:00.32
  Exit code: 1
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

### Tried

I have tried to:

- run VS as Administrator
- understand/modify MSBuild\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets (138, 5) - it goes over my head
- create VS project in user home folder. Calling the file test.vcxproj using command "MSBuild.exe test.vcxproj" - everything is working.
- compare vcxproj file created by Cmake and by VS.

#### Possible solutions

- created local accout with normal user name

  1. move all data to new account (I don't believe that everything will work - all settings, all programs)
  2. to eliminate switching between users/accounts - start VS with "run as another user" (run as user with normal name)

Is there some other solution that will work with the original user account (with parenthesis/es in name)?

### Example project

- test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
}
```

- CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(hello CXX)
add_executable(hello test.cpp)
```

- in the same folder as files are placed I create directory named build
- `cd build; cmake ..` => same error
- generated build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
            <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform>x64</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
        <ProjectGuid>{F3FC6D86-508D-3FB1-96D2-995F08B142EC}</ProjectGuid>
        <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
        <Platform>x64</Platform>
        <WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17763.0</WindowsTargetPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
        <ConfigurationType>Utility</ConfigurationType>
        <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
        <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props"/>
    <ItemDefinitionGroup>
        <PostBuildEvent>
            <Command>echo VCTargetsPath=$(VCTargetsPath)</Command>
        </PostBuildEvent>
    </ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets"/>
</Project>
```

- one can call MSBuild directly to obtain the same error as e.g. `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe" build\CMakeFiles\3.14.5\VCTargetsPath.vcxproj`

Comment: Are you sure that file paths supplied to cmake are properly quoted?

Comment: "Why/What is it trying to call from user folder?" - Without viewing the project we could only guess, like you do.

Comment: Any of cmake projects that I tested has the same problem. 

- I have updated question and placed minimal project that throws the same error.
- The vcxproj file generated by cmake was added too. There are no absolute paths.

Comment: Hi, can you share some details about `user account (domain, created using email) obtained name like PřijmeníJménoXXXXXX(`, I understand that your account name might be this, but I can't set similar name in windows10 1809, it doesn't allow me to create a name like this . So this issue could be hard to reproduce I guess ...

Comment: Hi, the original name was created automatically using email sign-in when creating account. Now I'm testing in virtual box with Windows 10 pro for Workstations, version 1809 - build 17763.775 installed. I can create any of these accounts ```PřijmeníJménoXXXXXX(```, ```PřijmeníJménoXXXXX()```. Shorter name ```user(```, ```user()``` can be used to reproduced same error (only the parenthesis is important).

Comment: According to your description maybe this issue has nothing to do with cmake. Please copy the VCTargets.vcxproj to a new folder in your virtual box, and then use msbuild.exe to build it, let me know the result:) If it provides the same error, I think this issue is that in an account with `(`, msbuild xx.vcxproj will cause unknown issue... Any update feel free to let me know :)

Comment: I have tested it and I think also that this problem is related to msbuild.exe and ```(``` than to cmake. If I create simple console application in VS and call ```msbuild.exe created.vcxproj``` everything is working (there is no step that needs to access ```c:\Users\user(```). The best solution is to avoid Win to create username containing ```(``` or/and fix VS msbuild.exe. The question related to Cmake could be: Could Cmake (using some params) create vcxproj with different structure (like in simple console App) that will not be affected with this error?

Comment: Hi, for `create VS project in user home folder. Calling the file test.vcxproj using command "MSBuild.exe test.vcxproj" - everything is working.` Have you tried copy the cmake-generated `VCTargetsPath.vcxproj` file to `C\user` folder or `C\User\PřijmeníJménoXXXXXX(` folder, same result?(succeed or fail). Is the G drive a mapping one?

Comment: The same if user name contain spaces and/or brackets (e.g. from Azure Domain).